# mod_rewrite load css and js if file not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have these lines in my `httpd.conf` which make the all the url as a single parameter (`'name'`) and when I type an name that doesen't exist index.php is loaded properly and a 404 message is shown. But the problem is that `JavaScript, CSS and other assets are not loaded.` How to load those files even if a dir/ file doesn't exists. ? I'm using `relative paths`. Thanks ;)

```
<Directory  "c:/Apache24/htdocs/public">
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the `FallbackResource` directive is a cleaner and more performant way to achieve what you're trying to do here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

Instead of the `mod_rewrite` stuff, just write this:

```
FallbackResource index.php
```

Inside the PHP script you can then turn the `PATH_INFO` environment variable into whatever you're using to capture the `name` argument.

Comment: Can you explain me why this is faster and more performant than mod_rewrite? I did this in `httpd.conf`  but now how can I get the name variable from the url via `PATH_INFO` if my url for ex. is sth like `http://localhost/john` ? Thanks @djc

Comment: I think this will treat all the url as non existent because `name` variable will be dynamic. and there will not be a file 'name.php'